# Are there alternate or secret exits for some levels in New Super Mario Bros for Wii?

Tags: mario-series, new-super-mario-bros-wii

In Super Mario World on the Super NES (16-bit), some levels on the world map were represented by a different-colored globe, which indicated that there were secret exits hidden on them that would open up a new path.  This usually involved finding a hidden lock and key, and reuniting them.

In New SMB for Wii, there appears to be a similar setup.   Is the same true, and if so, what colors indicate that there are multiple exits?

Comment: Too general. Yes in a lot of levels.

Short answer : yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 14 secret goals to be found in the game.

here's the [list](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/960544-new-super-mario-bros-wii/faqs/58291?print=1#section243) and where they are.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are secret exits, but I don't believe there's a color to indicate multiple exits. You just have to figure it out, but the hint videos might be able to provide some assistance.